# How can I use regex to remove a very specific portion of a string:

Tags: python, regex

I was wondering how I can use regex to remove a specific portion of a string. For example, I have a list that looks like this:

```
name=derek;
name=derek.1;
name=derek.2; 
name=derek.3;
name=ophelia;
name=ophelia.1;
name=ophelia.2;
name=ophelia.3;
```

I want to replace the characters after 'name=' and between either the '.' if present or the ';' at the end of the line. The output should look like this list:

```
name=apple;
name=apple.1;
name=apple.2; 
name=apple.3;
name=apple;
name=apple.1;
name=apple.2;
name=apple.3;
```

Comment: What regular expression did you try?

Comment: I tried: /^(.*?);/ but to no avail....

Comment: Well you're not trying to stop at `;`, you're trying to stop at either `;` or `.`, so it should be clear what change to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a multiline regex for this:

```
>>> print(s)
name=derek;
name=derek.1;
name=derek.2; 
name=derek.3;
name=ophelia;
name=ophelia.1;
name=ophelia.2;
name=ophelia.3;
>>> replace_with = r'\1{0}\2'.format('apple')  # preserve start & end
                                               # replace only the middle
>>> regex = '^(name=)[^\.;]+(.*)$'
>>> replaced = re.sub(regex,                # pattern
...                   replace_with,         # replacement
...                   s,                    # an original multiline string
...                   flags=re.MULTILINE);  # regex for multiple lines
>>> print(replaced)
name=apple;
name=apple.1;
name=apple.2; 
name=apple.3;
name=apple;
name=apple.1;
name=apple.2;
name=apple.3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but here's a version that doesn't need regex at all:

```
s = """name=derek;
name=derek.1;
name=derek.2; 
name=derek.3;
name=ophelia;
name=ophelia.1;
name=ophelia.2;
name=ophelia.3;"""

lines = s.split("\n")
updated = []
for line in lines:
    left, right = line.split("=")
    if "." in right:
        new_right = "apple." + right.split(".")[1]
    else:
        new_right = "apple;"
    updated.append(left + "=" + new_right)

print "\n".join(updated)
```