# How to code this identity in regex?

Tags: python, regex

This is out of curiosity as I am getting my head around the confusing world of regex.

I have a list like this:

```
ID=maker.abc_g1_1G252;
ID=maker.abc_g1_1G252.1;
ID=maker.abc_g1_1G252.1.exon1; 
ID=maker.abc_g1_1G252.1.CDS1;
```

I want to replace the 'maker.abc_g1_1G252'.

How can I first identify this string with a pattern in regex? Ultimately I will use this as a way to replace this pattern.

E.g.

```
ID=betty;
ID=betty.1;
ID=betty.1.exon1; 
ID=betty.1.CDS1;
```

For example, I could use the pattern  `ID=(.*?)[;/]`. But this will take me up to the ;. If I tried to replace with this pattern, I would get rid of the .1 information.

Comment: What does "a list like this" mean? You've assigned four different things to `ID`, none of which can be identified based on this code. Is that a text file you want to process? How can you distinguish between the things you want to match (presumably including `maker.abc_g1_1G252` and `betty.1.CDS1`) and things you _don't_ want to match (which you haven't explained at all)?

Comment: Maybe [`ID=\w+\.\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/B1mn2V/2) will do?

Comment: So why not just use `string.replace('maker.abc_g1_1G252', 'betty')`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, "I don't simply want to replace 'maker.abc_g1_1G252' as my list contains multiple maker identities, all with the same number of letters and numbers". But I don't think that's a clear description, as the second example doesn't seem to match the first in terms of "number of letters and numbers". (I understand that to be a second input, not a desired output.)

Comment: Or [`^(ID=)\w+\.\w+((?:\.\w+)*;)$`](https://regex101.com/r/B1mn2V/3/)?

Comment: @Chris: my point is more that the question is unclear, and possibly making it harder than it needs to be.

Comment: I'm with you there, @MartijnPieters.

Comment: I answered a very similar question yesterday:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43016308/how-can-i-use-regex-to-remove-a-very-specific-portion-of-a-string/43016585#43016585

Comment: I really apologise for this post - I found it quite difficult to express my question, but it seems that Wiktor has figured it out. Thank you

Comment: Ah yes, does seem similar. Your code for a regex alternative is helpful, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `regex`, a simple `replace` is enough, i.e.:

```
string = """ID=maker.abc_g1_1G252;
ID=maker.abc_g1_1G252.1;
ID=maker.abc_g1_1G252.1.exon1; 
ID=maker.abc_g1_1G252.1.CDS1;"""

print string.replace("maker.abc_g1_1G252", "betty")
```

You really want to use a regex, try something like:

```
result = re.sub("maker.*?1G252", "betty", subject, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
```

---

[Demo](http://ideone.com/DhNJe1)

Comment: You don't need `DOTALL` here.